# Spark IndexedRDD for Scala 2.11.x

Tags: apache-spark

I am referring to the project here: https://github.com/amplab/spark-indexedrdd

My questions are:

1. Is this still maintained? I noticed the last commit was in Sep 2015
2. Are there plans to add a 2.11.x version on Maven?
3. Are there any plans to add the Indexed RDDs into Spark Core?

Writing this I also realise the Spark project uses Scala 2.10.x. Is there any reason why there hasn't been a move to 2.11?

Comment: I guess spark scala version (2.10.x) is the main reason why didn't indexedrdd developers introduce version for 2.11

Comment: Spark supports Scala 2.11. It's just a decision that has been made regardless the version of scala. Reynold Xin didn't want it in spark-core.

Comment: Could you either accept the answer or explain why it doesn't work for you so it can be improved? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe it is still maintained but you should open an issue on their [github repo](https://github.com/amplab/spark-indexedrdd) to check that directly with the authors.

Thus, also the point concerning adding Scala 2.11 support should be answered there.

Concerning spark-core integration, there is a [JIRA discussion](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-2365) about the topic. The project seems to be initiated as a pull request into spark-core but finally, they made a decision about keeping it as a separate package for now.

Comment: They already have that issue
https://github.com/amplab/spark-indexedrdd/issues/12

Comment: Well since the authors seems not to reply on the project's issue tracker, this means it is not actually maintained.